# Navigation Submenu Disappears on Mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm editing a client's site created by another developer, which uses the Simple Slide Show plugin. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-slide-show/ I've tried to contact the developer, but believe they may no longer be supporting this plugin.

I'm working on resolving an issue with the homepage navigation menu. One of the submenus is very long, and if I mouseover a certain point in the menu which overlaps the plugin, it disappears. [Edit: removed site url at client's request] The error occurs in Chrome, FF & Safari, and may also occur in other browsers.

This may very possibly be unrelated to the plugin, but I'm exploring all options, and this seemed like a good thing to check. The reason I think it may be a plugin issue is that this bug only occurs on the homepage.

Thank you for taking a look!

Edit: Figured it out - thanks! The #naviwrapper z-index was set to 100 instead of 1.

Comment: Can you provide code and/or example using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: the question is meaningless without the code